# keycloak Invalid parameter: redirect_uri ( Azure )

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service, keycloak, keycloak-services

I have installed `keycloak` along with `postgresql` onto `Azure` platform using below docker compose file.

```
version: '3'
volumes:
  postgres_data:
      driver: local
services:
  postgres:
      image: postgres
      volumes:
        - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
        POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  keycloak:
      image: jboss/keycloak
      environment:
        DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
        DB_ADDR: postgres
        DB_DATABASE: keycloak
        DB_USER: keycloak
        DB_SCHEMA: public
        DB_PASSWORD: password
        KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: Pa55w0rd
        # Uncomment the line below if you want to specify JDBC parameters. The parameter below is just an example, and it shouldn't be used in production without knowledge. It is highly recommended that you read the PostgreSQL JDBC driver documentation in order to use it.
        #JDBC_PARAMS: "ssl=true"
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
      depends_on:
        - postgres
```

using same setup on my local machine I am able to login with user `admin` and password `Pa55w0rd` , but when I deploy this onto `Azure` platform, I can see [**Welcom to Keycloak**](https://dockerkeycloak.azurewebsites.net/auth/) screen and a link to navigat to **Administration Console**

When I click on [**Administration Console**](https://dockerkeycloak.azurewebsites.net/auth/) link I am getting below error message

```
Invalid parameter: redirect_uri
```

[image]

Is there any way to set valid redirect uri for default `security-admin-console` client?

**Note** This setup works well on my local machine.

**UPDATE 1**
  Found [this link](https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2018-) which says that `It seems that keycloak doesn't like the https in the redirect.`
That might be the reason why its working on my local machine.  But not sure how to fix it using https enabled.

**UPDATE 2**
  Found [exact same bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-568?_sscc=t) raised by some one on `keycloak` Jira board but its closed.  It looks like it can be fixed by updating `keycloak.json` Any idea how it can be done on Azure platform using docker compose feature.

September/015647.html

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do the same, and facing the same problem did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Publish https port:

```
      ports:
        - 8443:8443
```

and use it for administration. Of course, you may use own cert instead of default selefsigned cert as well (just use volumes for `/etc/x509/https/tls.crt` and `/etc/x509/https/tls.key`).

Comment: Thanks,  I did that but still having same issue.  As per as Azure is concerned docker-compose is in preview.  so not sure why my changes are not reflected. May be will delete all the resources from Azure and deploy it again.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be a problem with your Azure docker-compose. It works on my machine.